# VBA code for date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am working on some code for updating the report. When I use the date in the code, the code doesn't work, but if I use the exact string "22/08/2018", it works.

```
today = InputBox("Put in a date (yyyymmdd)")
mm = Mid(today,5,2)
yyyy = Left(today,4)
dd = Right(today,2)
date = dd & "/" & mm & "/" & yyyy

For each cell in Workbooks("a").Worksheets("1").Range("A1":"AZ1000")

  If cell.value = date
    rownumber = cell.row
    a = Cells(rownumber - 13, 13).Value
  End If

Next
```

The above code doesn't work. But if I change date to exact "22/08/2018" in "if" condition, it works and give me a correct value.

Anyone can help me, please.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?" What are you seeing? Error messages?

Comment: Your date is is DD/MM/YYYY form, and is stored as a string that way. However, most Excel dates are stored as a number, for example 9/22/2017 is 43000. So when you parse out the .value2, it gets the number, not the date. Value gets the number, but it can run into other issues